# Is it possible to develop QT application inside Symbian phone (e.g. E90)?

Tags: qt, symbian

Actually question is on subject and I think very clear. Just wondering is it possible to develop symbian application on phone?

Comment: What do you mean by "inside"? Check this out: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/12/12/start-with-qt-4-7-for-symbian-today/

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear.

Do you mean to ask whether it's possible to run the Qt *development tools* on the phone? The answer is no.

Do you mean whether it's possible to develop Qt applications for Symbian phone? The answer is very much yes - in fact, Nokia has made it abundantly clear that Qt is the main development platform for all their phones, going forward.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, like, can you develop an application for your phone using just your phone and not  a desktop/laptop?

No, not really, but you could install [PyS60](http://www.pys60.org/) and use a text editor in your phone to write python programs, though that might be a very broad interpretation of an "application" :).